# Get a value or values with a max and a count in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im stuck and I really need your help. Im using postgres and I have a inner join sql query that gets the count of number of groups that a member is apart of.

The result is

```
antal       fornamn
3           Anna
2           Sara
3           Lisa
1           Peter
```

I need to get the rows that have the highest values it can be one row or two rows, if it has the same value. I tried to use a max but it didnt work like I wanted it to I only got one row and column with the result

```
antal
3
```

I don't know were to put MAX. I want the result to be in this case

```
antal       fornamn
3           Anna
3           Lisa
```

the sql query so far is

```
SELECT COUNT(traningsgruppid) AS antal, medlem.fornamn
FROM traningsgrupprad
INNER JOIN medlem ON traningsgrupprad.medlemsid = medlem.medlemsid
GROUP BY medlem.fornamn
```

I tried this but It didnt work

```
SELECT COUNT(traningsgruppid) AS antal, medlem.fornamn
FROM traningsgrupprad
INNER JOIN medlem ON traningsgrupprad.medlemsid = medlem.medlemsid
WHERE antal = (SELECT MAX(antal) FROM traningsgrupprad)
GROUP BY medlem.fornamn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window/ranking functions:

```
SELECT m.antal, m.fornamn
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS antal, m.fornamn,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM traningsgrupprad t INNER JOIN
           medlem m
           ON t.medlemsid = m.medlemsid
      GROUP BY m.fornamn
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

I replaced `COUNT(traningsgruppid)` with `COUNT(*)` because something called an "id" is not usually `NULL`, so the two are equivalent (and the latter easier to type).